# Approaching Dynamic Programming problem / Two restrictions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

**Given an array A of n integers and k <= n, we want to choose k numbers from this array and split them to pairs, such that the sum of the differences of those pairs (in absolute value) is minimal.**

**Example**: If n = 8 and k = 6 and the array is A = [140, 100, 92, 21, 32, 48, 32, 100], then the optimal answer is 27.

Does someone have an idea?
Where do I start from in this problem?
I'm really bad at DP problems, so I would appreciate an informative answer describing the right approach to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any example...?

Comment: @YashShah Added. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: how optimal could be 27...?

Comment: @YashShah That's how the problem is given...

Comment: link to the problem...?

Comment: @YashShah Sorry but it's from rehearsal questions for the final. It's written originally in Hebrew...

Comment: I will translate that problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort elements. Now pairs ought to be made only with neighbors (for cases like 10,20,20,30 pairing 10/20 + 20/30 gives the same result as 10/30 + 20/20, for cases like 10,14,20 pair 10/20 is worse than 10/14 or 14/10)

Walk through array.

If pair is opened with the last element, we have the only possibility - close that pair with current element

If there is no opened pair and number of closed pairs is less than k/2, we have two possibilities - start pair or omit current element (if number of elements in the rest of array is larger than we must use), and we have to choose the best result from these cases.

So we can build recursion and then transform it into DP (code below is not DP yet, it builds full solution tree).

```
A = [140, 100, 92, 21, 32, 48, 32, 100]
n = len(A)
k = 6

def best(idx, openstate, pairsleft):
    if pairsleft > (n - idx + 1)//2:
        return  10000000
    if pairsleft == 0:
        return 0

    if openstate:
        return abs(A[idx] - A[idx-1]) + best(idx + 1, False, pairsleft - 1)
    else:
        return(min(best(idx + 1, True, pairsleft), best(idx + 1, False, pairsleft)))

A.sort()
print(best(0, False, k//2))

>> 27
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I didn't understand the terminology - what do you mean by opened/closed pairs?

Comment: We chose the first element of pair - we opened this pair. We got the second element -we closed this pair, and now can make the next pair